# NodeJS sqlite database cant open

Tags: javascript, node.js, sqlite

i've tried everything, changing the database name, restarting my pc, ending the nodejs application and starting over however for some reason my database simply cant be opened. it worked perfectly past that but now all of a sudden it just doesn't work.

Heres my code

```
// Setting up the Database
let db = new sqlite3.Database('todo.db', sqlite3.OPEN_READONLY, (err) => {
    if (err) {
      console.error(err.message);
    }
    console.log('Connected to the Todo app database.');
});
```

Comment: what happens when you try - what's the error?

Comment: SQLITE_CANTOPEN

Comment: What happens when you try to open the database with the [`sqlite3` command line tools](https://sqlite.org/download.html)? Have you tried an absolute path?

Comment: Try absolute paths per this discussion: https://github.com/electron/electron/issues/4644#issuecomment-204365747

Answer (score 0):

ANSWER: i figured the reason it didn't work was because the file wasn't created? this is weird because at first it created the file by itself.